# How to know where terminal name (command line prompt) come from?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, ubuntu-16.04

When I log in on remote server with my `user`, I see terminal name:
`user@someName`. I want to modify `someName` part.

I thought maybe it was related with hostname. So opening `/etc/hostname`, it was also named `someName`. But even after changing `hostName`, terminal name did not change (I tried logging out and logging in back).

Also that user does not have `.bashrc` file created.

Comment: You're asking two seperate questions in this single post. It's better to ask a single question in a single post, that will yield the best QA style answers.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski what are you talking about?:) I only see one question. I was asking to know where terminal name was coming from. And other insights in question where just details what I was trying to do.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski no its not. Its just my assumption that maybe there is something else I dont know. Its like having a question "why my car does not start". And then you can write some follow ups, like maybe it ran out of gas (but you dont know where the tank is, so you cant answer that)? But can delete that if its bothering you..

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski read the question again. The question is regarding terminal name not how to change hostname. The only relation with hostname, is that my assumption that terminal name outputs hostname. And I mentioned `bashrc`, because it is usually used to display terminal name. But I dont see such file.

Comment: The question was the same all the time. I wanted to know where my terminal name came from. My assumption was that part after `@` came from hostname (because there is no `bashrc` file). So I tried to change hostname. But I was not aware that restart is required to have it really changed:). And what you are asking is like remove all the details that are not about terminal name directly (even if its related as with `hostname`).

Comment: OK, my mistake then. I apologize. What "terminal name" are you referring to? Is it about your command line prompt? If so, investigate `PS1` variable.

Comment: Maybe my term was wrong, yes `command line prompt`

Comment: Please note it's not very clear on what level you want to change `someName`. Example: here on Super User I'm presenting myself as Kamil Maciorowski which is my legal name. If I asked how to change the `Maciorowski` part, there would be two answers: (1) edit my profile on Super User, (2) initiate whatever legal procedure my state provides to change my last name. // `sudo hostname` solution is like (2); manipulating `PS1` variable is like (1). The only difference is my profile won't automatically update if I change my legal name.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski you comment is valid in case only if user asking question knows all these things. Imagine user knowing only that he wants to change command prompt part, but he does not know there is even `PS1` variable (so he does not mention how specifically to change it). But if user would know all these things he probably would not even write a question in a first place. Yes I knew about `PS1`, but did not think about that when I was writing question. You need to be aware that some people might not know everything else except specific thing they are asking :)

Comment: Yes [you're very right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_knowledge). I guess we both learned something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/hostname` will only be read at boot time, so unless you reboot your host, it won't update the hostname of the machine.

You can update the hostname of the machine without rebooting by running the `hostname` command, like so:

```
mtak@rubiks:~$ sudo hostname otherhostname
mtak@rubiks:~$ bash
mtak@otherhostname:~$
```

or by having it read the `/etc/hostname` file:

```
mtak@otherhostname:~$ less /etc/hostname
rubiks
mtak@otherhostname:~$ sudo hostname -F /etc/hostname
mtak@otherhostname:~$ bash
mtak@rubiks:~$
```

After changing the hostname, it might be a good idea to reboot the host anyway, since all running daemons that use the hostname won't automatically update (eg. Apache will still display *Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at someName Port 80*).

Comment: If I do that, it will output: `sudo: unable to resolve host some_new_host` (in both scenarios you described)

Comment: After running `sudo hostname -F /etc/hostname` multiple times, it did change now. Stange.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, the name of the computer is stored in three different locations: there is /etc/hostname, the variable $HOSTNAME the shell uses, & some place X pulls it from that is different from the other two. (I found it once, years ago, but don't remember where I found it except that I had to scour thru the startx scripts.)

As you've been told above, changing /etc/hostname is not enough. You also need to change it in the shell with "hostname -F /etc/hostname". Or reboot your computer.